# Dynamically Show View in yii2 advance

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components, yii2-basic-app

Hello i am working on web application in yii2 advance.i am new in yii2 development. In this project i want to show some part of body refreshed  ajax request like in facebook  when we click on Home just post area refresh, In my application i want same kind of functionality in my application.When i clicked on tab  tab content change accordion to the tab clicked , change the html completely for tab section, is their any extension available their which provide same kind of functionality or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes One Very good extension is available to fulfill your need that is kartik tabs-x.

Demo ink ==> http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x

Download Url ==> https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x

Hope this will help you.